# How to convert a char (numeric 0-9) to int without getNumericalValue?

Tags: java, casting, char, converters, numeric

I'd like to know if it's possible, at all, to convert a char numeric (0-9) into an int without the use of character.getNumericalValue. Casts aren't possible either.

Getting the raw value of a char at the moment gives me the ascii value, which obviously is not what i want.

Just to be a little clearer, i am 100% sure that there won't be any other kind of ascii value in the char i use in my code other than numeric values that range from 0 to 9.

And i'm just being curious here (couldn't find this on google when i searched for it) but what's the underlying code of getNumericalValue? How does it find if a caracter is numeric or not? With a switch case? (i really hope not, that'd be dirty!)

Anyway, here's some pseudo code that illustrate what i'm trying to accomplish :

```
char c = '';
int i;
c = 1 caracter from user input (0-9)
i = c (to int) -> ?????
```

Comment: Hint: you can subtract 2 chars (and [ascii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart)).

Comment: Can't you just check if the ASCII value range is between 48-57 inclusive? EDIT: Scrap that, miss read, my bad... you want the number, not just to know if it is a number:(

Comment: You are... Totally right. How come i didn't think about this before.

Comment: @PaulHickman i already do that, and combined with a substraction (@RC), it actually does what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're 100% sure that the char will only have numbers 0-9 then you can cast it to an int like so.

```
char c = '5';
int i = (int) c - 48;
```

Link to Character open jdk source if you're interested in the code beind getNumericalValue().
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#Character

Answer (score 0):

```
char c = '9';
int val = (int)c - 48;
```

There are not error check, that is depends on how you want to implement it and what the input would be